# Problema con conexion DB Oracle 9i ASP.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, oracle, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Actualmente estoy usando **Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client** para realizar las conexiones a la base de datos de Oracle desde ASP MVC.NET ,tengo varias conexiones y todas se puede conectar el problema viene cuando me trato de conectar a la base de datos de *Oracle 9i* me arroja el siguiente mensaje

> **ORACLE.MANAGEDDATAACCESS.CLIENT.ORACLEEXCEPTION (0X80004005): ORA-12514: TNS:EL LISTENER NO CONOCE ACTUALMENTE EL SERVICIO SOLICITADO EN EL DESCRIPTOR DE CONEXIÓN**

---

el cual me aparece cuando mando a llamar para abrir la conexion.

**Error completo:**

> ORACLE.MANAGEDDATAACCESS.CLIENT.ORACLEEXCEPTION (0X80004005): ORA-12514: TNS:EL LISTENER NO CONOCE ACTUALMENTE EL SERVICIO SOLICITADO EN EL DESCRIPTOR DE CONEXIÓN ---> ORACLEINTERNAL.NETWORK.NETWORKEXCEPTION (0X000030E2): ORA-12514: TNS:EL LISTENER NO CONOCE ACTUALMENTE EL SERVICIO SOLICITADO EN EL DESCRIPTOR DE CONEXIÓN
>      EN ORACLEINTERNAL.NETWORK.ORACLECOMMUNICATION.DOCONNECT(STRING TNSDESCRIPTOR)
>      EN ORACLEINTERNAL.NETWORK.ORACLECOMMUNICATION.CONNECT(STRING TNSDESCRIPTOR, BOOLEAN DONAHANDSHAKE, STRING INAME)
>      EN ORACLEINTERNAL.SERVICEOBJECTS.ORACLECONNECTIONIMPL.CONNECT(CONNECTIONSTRING CS, BOOLEAN BOPENENDUSERSESSION, CRITERIACTX CRITERIACTX, STRING INSTANCENAME)
>      EN ORACLEINTERNAL.CONNECTIONPOOL.POOLMANAGER
>   3.GET(CONNECTIONSTRING CSWITHDIFFORNEWPWD, BOOLEAN BGETFORAPP, CRITERIACTX CRITERIACTX, STRING AFFINITYINSTANCENAME, BOOLEAN BFORCEMATCH)
>      EN ORACLEINTERNAL.CONNECTIONPOOL.ORACLEPOOLMANAGER.GET(CONNECTIONSTRING CSWITHNEWPASSWORD, BOOLEAN BGETFORAPP, CRITERIACTX CRITERIACTX, STRING AFFINITYINSTANCENAME, BOOLEAN BFORCEMATCH)
>      EN ORACLEINTERNAL.CONNECTIONPOOL.ORACLECONNECTIONDISPENSER3.GET(CONNECTIONSTRING CS, PM CONPM, CONNECTIONSTRING PMCS, SECURESTRING SECUREDPASSWORD, SECURESTRING SECUREDPROXYPASSWORD, CRITERIACTX CRITERIACTX)
>      EN ORACLE.MANAGEDDATAACCESS.CLIENT.ORACLECONNECTION.OPEN()

**Este la clase en donde tengo la conexion:**

```
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Interface.Models
{
public class Ora_Conexion
{
    private OracleConnection cn { get; set; }

    public OracleConnection getConn()
    {
        if (cn == null)
        {
            string conexion = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CONEXION_ORACLE"].ToString();
            cn = new OracleConnection(conexion);

        }
        return cn;
    }
}
}
```

Cadena de Conexion en el confing:

```
<add key="CONEXION_ORACLE" value="DATA SOURCE=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1521/xxxx;PASSWORD=123;USER ID=RANDOM" />
```

La sintaxis es la que uso para realizar las demás conexiones a las Bases de datos.
Las otras conexiones que realizo son otras versiones superiores de Oracle 
Espero me puedan ayudar.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo compañeros solo tenia que descargar el cliente correcto , en mi caso descargue el **client/ODP.NET Driver version 11.2 or older.**

Comment: Marca la respuesta como aceptada haciendo click en el check verde del costado

Answer (score 0):

¿Tienes los drivers bien instalados?

El error:

> EL LISTENER NO CONOCE ACTUALMENTE EL SERVICIO SOLICITADO EN EL DESCRIPTOR DE CONEXIÓN

Me hace pensar que tiene un problema en la cadena de conexión, por favor verifica la cadena que utilizas:

```
DATA SOURCE=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1521/xxxx;PASSWORD=123;USER ID=RANDOM
```

Revisa este formato:

```
Data Source=username/password@myserver//nombreDeTuInstancia;
```

**Actualización:**

```
Data Source=MyOracleDB;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Integrated Security=no;
```

Referencia: https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/

Comment: intente cambiandola cadena, pero ahora me marca este mensaje: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-12154: TNS:no se ha podido resolver el identificador de conexión especificado ---> OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException (0x00002F7A): ORA-12154: TNS:no se ha podido resolver el identificador de conexión especificado  
Data Source=ADQUIS/admtu160501@100.00.000.7:1521//mty

Comment: solo por curiosidad, ¿ambas computadoras están en la misma red?

Comment: asi es, desde sqldeveloper si puedo conectarme , pero cuando trato de hacer la conexion en c# me marca el error

Comment: acabo de actualizar la respuesta, prueba con ello :D