# ¿Cómo conectarse a una versión vieja de Oracle(Oracle 9i) desde C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy tratando de realizar una conexión desde C# hacia una base de datos de Oracle la cual es Oracle 9i al momento de usar la clase que normalmente tengo para realizar las conexiones a Oracle me marca el siguiente mensaje

> **ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied**

Las credenciales están bien , si trato de iniciar desde el sqldeveloper , si puedo entrar sin problemas

```
ing Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace testConexion.CONN
{
    public class Ora_Conexion_ADQUIS
    {
        private OracleConnection cn { get; set; }

        public OracleConnection getConn()
        {
            if (cn == null)
            {

            string pass = "Password=admtu160741;";
                //string conexion = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CONEXION_ORACLE_ADQUIS"].ToString();
                /*string conexion = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=000.00.000.0)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=mtu)));User Id = ADQUIS; Password = admtu160741;";*/
                string conexion = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=000.00.000.0)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=MTU)));User Id = adquis;"+pass;
                //string conexion = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=000.00.000.0)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SID=mtu)));User Id=adquis;Password=admtu160741;";
                //string conexion= "DATA SOURCE = 000.00.000.0:1521 / MTU; PASSWORD = admtu160741; USER ID = ADQUIS";

                cn = new OracleConnection(conexion);

            }
            return cn;
        }
    }
}
```

**Tengo la versión de Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client V. 12.1.2416** ya la cambié a la mas reciente y nada , intenté con la última que está en el nuget pero no me deja. Alguna idea de qué me falte hacer? o cómo hacerla de otra forma?. No puedo actualizar la bd a la versión mas reciente ya que es la del trabajo y es con la que se está trabajando actualmente.

Comment: Por qué haces varias preguntas con el mismo problema?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Problema con conexion DB Oracle 9i ASP.NET](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/311938/problema-con-conexion-db-oracle-9i-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

Esa versión de ODAC no funciona para 9i.

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/install121012-2088160.html

> Access to an Oracle Database Server (Oracle 10g Release 2 or later)

Usa una versión compatible.

Comment: Tendria que bajar el visual studio 2012 vdd o el ODT funcionaria tambien en el 2017?